adding a new line to the Julia Data Frame document by timer
adding a new line to the Julia Data Frame document by timer.
I'm sorry, the text was translated from Russian with a Google translator.
I am unsuccessfully trying to add a new and subsequent lines to the frame by timer for processing and plotting.
1 .Data - timer 1 minute/
2 .updated timer data/
3 and so on/
4///////
I need the data collected for the day saved in this table and overwritten by a timer.
I was trying to figure out the CSV and DataFrame libraries
But I only found the "append!" function
here is my code
using  HTTP, Gumbo, Cascadia, AbstractTrees, Dates, DataFrames, Tables, CSV

function parsing_html_coin()

r = HTTP.get("https://www.okx.com/ru/markets/explore/crypto-market-cap"; cookies=Dict("experiment"=>"true"))
r_parsed = parsehtml(String(r.body))
coin  = r_parsed.root[2]

coin_name_1 = coin[2][1][1][2][2][2][1][1][2][1][2][1][1][1] #укажите точноее название монеты
coin_price_1 = coin[2][1][1][2][2][2][1][1][2][1][4][2][1]   #точная цена монеты
coin_capitalization_1 = coin[2][1][1][2][2][2][1][1][2][1][3][1] # рыночная капитализация
coin_sold_1 = coin[2][1][1][2][2][2][1][1][2][1][6][1] # обьем проданных монет
coin_total_turnover = coin[2][1][1][2][2][2][1][1][2][1][7][1] #общий оборот от проданных монет

coin_name_string_1 = String(string((coin_name_1))) #перевод имени в тип string
coin_price_string_1 = String(string((coin_price_1))) #перевод цены в тип  string
coin_capitalization_string_1 = String(string((coin_capitalization_1))) #перевод капитализации
coin_sold_string_1 = String(string((coin_sold_1))) #обьем проданных монет в тип string
coin_total_turnover_string_1 = String(string((coin_total_turnover))) #общее количество

Name = coin_name_string_1   # название монеты
coin_1_replace = replace(coin_price_string_1,'\$'=>' ',','=>'.') #очистка лишних символов
coin_1_delete_backspace = filter(x -> !isspace(x), coin_1_replace) # очистка от пробелов
Bitcoin = parse.(Float64,coin_1_delete_backspace) # перевод монет в тип флоат

coin_2_replace = replace(coin_capitalization_string_1,'\$'=>' ',','=>'.','B'=>' ') #очистка
coin_2_delete_backspace = filter(x -> !isspace(x), coin_2_replace) # очистка от пробелов
Сapitalization = parse.(Float64,coin_2_delete_backspace) # перевод монет в тип флоат

coin_3_replace = replace(coin_sold_string_1,'B'=>' ','T'=>' ','C'=>' ') #очистка лишних символов
coin_3_delete_backspace = filter(x -> !isspace(x), coin_3_replace) # очистка от пробелов
Sold = parse.(Float64,coin_3_delete_backspace) # перевод монет в тип флоат для дальнейшей работы

coin_4_replace = replace(coin_total_turnover_string_1,'$'=>' ',','=>'.','M'=>' ','B'=>' ')
coin_4_delete_backspace = filter(x -> !isspace(x), coin_4_replace) # очистка от пробелов
Total = parse.(Float64,coin_4_delete_backspace) # перевод монет в тип флоат


return Name, Bitcoin, Сapitalization, Sold, Total

end


function main(intervalminutes = 1, nruns = 9)
    for _ in 1:nruns
        a,b,c,d,e = parsing_html_coin()
        my_time = Dates.now() # точное время
        #Exact_time = Dates.format(my_time, "HH:MM   dd u yyyy") # время в нужном формате
        return a,b,c,d,e,my_time
        sleep(intervalminutes *  30)
        
    end  
end   
closeread(main)

function tete()

    a,b,c,d,e,my_time = main()
    Exact_time = Dates.format(my_time, "HH:MM   dd u yyyy") # время в нужном формате
    k = 100
    df = DataFrame("Name coin"=>a,"Price"=>b,"Сapitalization"=>c,"Sold"=>d,"Total"=>e,"Date and    time"=>Exact_time,"Price change wedge"=>k)
    CSV.write("data.csv", df)
    ExampleInputDF = CSV.read("data.csv", DataFrame)
    
end
tete()


